# How can I specify which android build tools version in Maven

Tags: android, maven, build-tools

Looks like the Android Maven plugin always uses the latest build tools version by default.  Is there a way to specify a specific version?

This link seems to indicate so but I can't figure out how to specify the value in my POM file.

https://github.com/simpligility/android-maven-plugin/commit/a52d218964b0fa75db751954b15e316f5b0d3aa4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Starting from version 4.3.0](http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/changelog.html#4_3_0_released_2015_06_15), you can specify a build tools version at the configurations section of the android plugin. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.3</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>                    
      <sdk>
        <platform>25</platform>
        <buildTools>25.0.2</buildTools>
      </sdk>
    </configuration>         
</plugin>
```

Comment: could not use the 24.x.x build tools because of a glibc conflict on our build machine. This saved my bacon :) thanks.